# Laravel - get values of relation to the same model

Tags: php, laravel

I have my User Table, which has a ID and a comes_from (id), which points to the id column of the same user table.

for example:

```
User
id, comes_from
1,  null
2,  1
```

So user with ID 2 comes from user with ID 1

Now I'm trying to build this.

I want to print out a table with all users I have and another table column which gives me the email of the user, that the current row user comes from.

My User model:

```
public function recruited()
    {
        return self::findOrFail($this->comes_from)->pluck('email', 'id');
    }
```

Now in my Controller:

```
  public function recruitedUsersList()
    {
        return view('admin.recruitedUsers')->with('users', User::all()->with('recruited'));
    }
```

This tells me "Call to undefined method with"

In my blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
       <tr>
             <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->recruited()->email }}</td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

Well.. this doesn't work for me. Does someone has a idea?

The Idea is:

A user can come from only one person. He get the "comes_from (id) as he register himself"
A User can recruite as many people as he wants.

Comment: For starters you forgot ->get() at the end; Also will with() even work since you're not defining a relationship?

Comment: uhm, the ->all() doesn't need a ->get() afterwards I think.. And if with will work.. well I don't know. I'm asking you guys :D If I do it without with() and just do $user->recruited()->email it also doesn't work

Comment: Have you set up any relationships in your `User` model?

Comment: yeah I have set up some relationshops in my user model.

Comment: They just don't belong to this problem, thats why I didn't wrote them down here

Comment: Have you defined a relationship called `recruited` on your user model?

Comment: uhm, well no, only this recruited() function in the user model. Thats not really a relationship.. youre right

Comment: OK so the `with()` function is really for use with relationships. add a `hasOne` relationship to your User model with the column name set as your 'comes from' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I assume a person can recruit more than one other person in your application. So I think `hasMany` relationship best describes this.

Update the function in your `User` Model

```
public function recruited()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'comes_from');
}
```

Update your controller to this

```
public function recruitedUsersList()
{
    return view('admin.recruitedUsers')->with('users', User::with('recruited')->get());
}
```

Update your view logic to this

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   <tr>
         <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
         <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
         <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
         <td>
            @foreach($user->recruited as $recruit)
               {{ $recruit->email }}, 
            @endforeach
         </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```